# Regular expression match against a string (blue:bar AND darkblue:foo) to darkblue

Tags: php, regex

I need to write me a regular expression which can match against a string starting with "(" or white space, ending with colon(both the starting and ending character should be excluded form the match result) and exclude the following three words(full match only): red, green, blue.

For example:

input 1: (green:bar AND black:foo)
match result: **black**

input 2: (blue:bar AND darkblue:foo)
match result: **darkblue**

input 3: (yellow:bar AND grey:foo)
match result: **yellow grey**

input 4: (greengarden:bar AND blue:foo)
match result: **greengarden**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is expected that you attempt to solve your problem then provide a [mcve] when asking a question. You can use [regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com/tests) to write tests and develop your RegEx.

Comment: I want to try on php

Comment: Give it a try, post what you have, and post what your issue(s) are.

Comment: First two inputs does not match the two following. Why is #3 and #4 not "grey" and "blue"

Comment: `(?:^\s*\(|\G(?!\A))[^)]*?\b(?!red\b|green\b|blue\b)(\w+)\b(?=:)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some patterns that I have written that work (in order of least efficient to most efficient in terms of "step count"):

Step counts are based on this sample input:

```
(green:bar AND black:foo)
(blue:bar AND darkblue:foo)
(yellow:bar AND grey:foo)
(greengarden:bar AND red:foo)
```

- `/(?:red|blue|green)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[a-z]+(?=:)/`  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xuMsR7/1) (513 steps)
- `/\b(?!red:|blue:|green:)[a-z]+(?=:)/` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xuMsR7/2) (372 steps)
- `/(?<=\(|AND )(?!red:|blue:|green:)[^:]*/` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xuMsR7/3) (319 steps)
- `/(?<=\(|AND )(?:(?:red:|blue:|green:)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[^:]+)/` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xuMsR7/4) (304 steps)
- `/(?:\(|AND )\K(?!red:|blue:|green:)[^:]*/` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xuMsR7/5) (291 steps)
- `/(?:\(|AND )\K(?!red\b|blue\b|green\b)[^:]+/` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xuMsR7/6) (291 steps)
- `/[( ]\K(?!red\b|blue\b|green\b)[a-z]+/` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xuMsR7/7) (172 steps)

This final pattern is the best performer and takes full advantage of the strict format of your input data -- pertaining to capitalization, opening parentheses, and the two spaces per line.

It finds the opening parenthesis or a space, then restarts the fullstring match using `\K`, disqualifies any substring that is wholly `red`, `blue`, or `green` and stops matching on the last lowercase letter.

In regex, speed gains are accomplished by using narrow character classes (`[]` & `[^]`), limiting alternatives (pipes `|`), "lookarounds", and capture/non-capture groups.

My patterns deliberately avoid making capture groups because they only lead to output array bloat.  All of your desired "color" substrings will be found in the fullstring [0] matches subarray that `preg_match_all()` returns.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/70bac9a4df1b7ddede01e5e0d34c2f7e9432af4f))

```
$string='(green:bar AND black:foo)
    (blue:bar AND darkblue:foo)
    (yellow:bar AND grey:foo)
    (greengarden:bar AND red:foo)';

var_export(preg_match_all('/[( ]\K(?!red\b|blue\b|green\b)[a-z]+/',$string,$out)?$out[0]:'fail');
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'black',
  1 => 'darkblue',
  2 => 'yellow',
  3 => 'grey',
  4 => 'greengarden',
)
```